# Is there a more modern program than lex or yacc, which does not require JVM?

Tags: compiler, parsing

Is there a "modern" bison and flex equivalent which does not require the JVM or .NET or similar "heavy" runtimes?

By modern, I mean for example [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) and another one in Java I saw but forgot the name of. (I know that for instance Antlr has a C target, but I am toying with the idea of embedding the compiler generator *inside my own program* and Java would be very impractical for me.)

Comment: Define "more modern".  What features or capabilities are you looking for that lex and yacc don't provide?

Comment: Is there a reason it should not require the JVM or .NET? Any computer made in the last decade (or more) would typically run them and be fine.

Comment: Like C++'s Boost.Spirit and Haskell's Parsec? Or do you explicitly want a language-neutral generator?

Comment: Since when to lex and/or yacc require JVM or .NET???

Comment: Lex and Yacc can do anything, but calling them easy to use, I wouldn't dare. I'd like to be able to embed the lexer in my program eventually, so I don't want to depend on JVM or something which may not be installed.

Comment: @CrazyEddie I think the OP meant ANTLR.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant If all you want to do is embed the lexer in your program, why not just use a regular expressions library?

Comment: Do you mean like flex bison.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: Dare accepted. I find them trivial to use (but I have written a lot of lexer/parser in my time). It is just another language (and both are very simple to use for a computer scientist that has a formal grounding in "regular expressions" and "Backus–Naur Form").

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant In languages like Antlr, you do need JVM to *generate* the lexer/parser code, but if you choose the "C++" target then once the code is generated, you no longer need the JVM at all. In other words, you'd need the JVM to compile the program, but not to run it.

Comment: I dare you to say that the Recursive desent version is easier to read! [Recursive Decent JSON parser in C++](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=SmqNbQG0) Vs [Shift Reduce JSON parser in BISON](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Re3tX77V). The bison(yacc) version is easier to read and took about an hour to write. The recursive decent version took about a day to get debugged and working correctly. Note. I am not saying these are the best tools (just the ones I am familiar with (I hear great things about ANTLR)).

Comment: I am not saying that handcoded recursive descent is better. As a non-computer scientist, I want to be held by the hand, more than Bison or yacc do... :) @LokiAstari

Comment: I tend to just make an efficient sax parser then hollow out the XML specific logic and make it dynamic enough to change what opens/closes a context and what current catches are. Very performant for many tasks as long as your target AST not more complex than XML. Using something with an API like so vs using generator is another potentially viable option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recommend using the [Lemon parser generator](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html) for parsing. Like Bison, it produces a parser in C. However, its grammar is less error-prone, the parsing interface is reentrant without global variables, and works by you giving tokens to the parser (instead of the parser calling you back to get tokens).

You don't really need a lexer generator (e.g. lex). It's usually easier to write it by hand.

You can check out some of my code to get an idea of how to parse a language using Lemon: [language](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/NCD), [lexer](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/ncd/NCDConfigTokenizer.c), [grammar](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/ncd/NCDConfigParser_parse.y), [parser](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/ncd/NCDConfigParser.c).

Comment: +1 Lemon looks really interesting! I will wait a little more for more answers before accepting this, but this looks like the winner.

Answer (score 5):

A very different but quite capable (and easily embeddable) answer is [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/).

At first glance is just a pattern matching library, like a more capable RegEx; but it allows you to define not only patterns but whole language grammars, attaching custom behaviour to any step.

On that page there's a sample that matches an arithmetic expression, and produces the final value.  It could instead produce a parse graph, or directly emit code.

The [LPEG Recipes](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LpegRecipes) page includes samples for whole Lua lexer and parsers, and also an ANSI C lexer.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Will go look at the ANSI C lexer now.

Answer (score 2):

Despite Ambroz Bizjak had told you that you wouldn't really need a lexer generator, you most probably will (unless you're fine with having to manually left-factor your token rules). I'd recommend you using [Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) instead of the old-school *lex* if you want to get a nice lexer with no global state.